Pygame not responding when i run it
Hello first time user to the site, i am having a problem with Pygame not responding and don't know what is wrong i would be most thankful for any kind of help.
here is the code
sorry if this is not proper formating
import pygame
pygame.init
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

while True:
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_a] == True:
        print('works')        


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Do you happen to get any errors?

You need to update your game loop. Your provided code is basically 'hung' because pygame is never checking any of it's events.
You can update your logic loop by getting game events from the queue. You also need to add parenthesis to the init call at the top
import pygame
pygame.init()  # Need to call this as a method. Added ()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

while True:
    # You need to get events from the queue
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # You can remove `== True` in if 
    if key[pygame.K_a] == True: statements too
        print('works')


https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get


thank your freddy mcloughlan for the answer code now works, also thank you for sharing the pygame quit function i was having a lot of trouble with that.
